# Motorola G7 takes ~80 seconds to open Discord and some other apps

Tags: motorola-moto-g, lagging, discord

I have a Moto G7 that is 2 years old.  Some apps take a super long time to open.  In general, the phone is pretty responsive, but 1/5th of apps are nearly unusable.

Right now, I am having pretty severe issues with Discord.  The app works on the phone but takes ~80 seconds to open when I have other things open.  If I have closed everything else on my phone, it will take around 30 seconds to open.  It will hang on the Discord logo on startup:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRMtWl.png)

Questions:

- Why is Discord so slow to open on my phone?
- How can I investigate this kind of issue?
- Is my phone damaged?
- Is my phone using a different chipset than other phones and some apps are not compiled for it?
- If I buy a new phone, what should I do to see if Discord (or other apps) will run fast?

---

Just to provide context, most apps open in under 1 second.  Apps that I just tested:

- LinkedIn
- Facebook
- Zoom
- Spotify
- Strava
- Garmin Earthmate
- Netflix
- ... etc

---

Info about my phone:

- Motorola G7
- Model Number: XT1962-4
- Hardware Version: PVT
- Android 10
- Discord Version: 106.12 - Stable

Comment: If the apps start faster if you close everything right before this might indicate a RAM problem (also the apps you mention are mostly pretty large). But your phone has 4GB RAM which is an average size which would make RAM problems unusual. If you want to monitor the start of e.g. Discord you can enable developer options and adb, connect you phone via USB to a PC, install adb on the PC and check `adb logcat` output while Discord is starting if something unusual is shown in the log.

Comment: Without knowing all the problematic apps, if it's about Discord, then there's a possibility that there's a network issue between the phone to the Discord server. Or if there are too many Discord servers to be refreshed.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I asked my freinds if it was slow for them - they said they are not having any issues.  One even has a Moto G6, which is especially puzzling.